# Start a mail program from command line and set subject with backslash

Tags: windows, batch-file, backslash

i need to have a windows bat file to open the email client and set subject with "COA\"

i tried this code but wit no success

```
@echo off

set desc=" COA\"

set desc=%desc:~1,-1%

start "title" "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\notes.exe" mailto:antonio@company.pt?subject=%desc%
```

but when i run it i get the email program to create automatically an email with subject filled with COA/ instead of COA\

How can i fix it to COA\ ?

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@echo off
    set "desc= COA%%5C"
    set "mailProgram=C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\notes.exe"

    start "" "%mailProgram%" mailto:antonio@company.pt?subject=%desc%
```

1. Encode the backslash (`\` = `%5C`). As we are working inside a batch file, the percent sign needs to be escaped doubling it.
2. It is a good idea to use quotes to prevent problems, but instead of including quotes in the variable value to later remove them, just quote the assignment.
3. `mailProgram` variable is not needed, just included to make easier to read the code.